# Is there any alternative to jQuery .ready?

Tags: jquery, joomla

I am checking window.height and content.height and giving dynamic height depending on the height of content. Why I am doing this? Because I want to put footer in the bottom when content is less.

So I have this code which works fine, with one exception.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       var s = jQuery(window).height();
       var n = jQuery("#content").height();
       if(n<s-270&&n>0)
            jQuery("#content").height(s-270);
        });
</script>
```

It is not working properly when I am going to this page http://bmsc.tfei.info/en/staff
which is using tab modules. When I refresh twice or more time it gets working.
What I want to check height of everything(window, content) after full loading.
Any advice?

Comment: sound like an image caching problem `$(window).load(function() {});` will execute when complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images

Comment: @Pete edited comment make more sense now ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, use window `onload` event:

```
jQuery(window).on('load',function(){
       var s = jQuery(window).height();
       var n = jQuery("#content").height();
       if(n<s-270&&n>0)
            jQuery("#content").height(s-270);
        });
```

This event is fired when all async elements (pictures,script) have been loaded.

And as you are inside a handler relative to window, you could write:

```
var s = jQuery(this).height();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `resize function` for this,

like,

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function test()
    {
           var s = jQuery(window).height();
           var n = jQuery("#content").height();
           if(n<s-270&&n>0)
                jQuery("#content").height(s-270);
    }

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
         test();
    });
    jQuery('window').on('resize',function(){
         test();
    });
    // you can call load and resize once like,

    jQuery('window').on('load resize',function(){
         test();
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: @roasted the last code will be an alternative, I wrote a comment for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(window).on('load',function() { 
 /* code goes here*/ 
});
```

Comment: What does this add to roasteds answer?